# matDatePicker ngModal issue in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Here is my Html code

```
 <div>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" [(ngModal)]="picker"  >
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</div>
```

Code in component.ts file

```
picker: Date;
    constructor(private httpservice: HttpservService) {} 

 ngOnInit() {
      this.picker = new Date();
  }
```

I have the issue in ngModal.I get the following error.

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModal' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. (" <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" [ERROR ->][(ngModal)]="picker"  >
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker"): 

    ng:///app/dashboard/dashboard.component.html@3:81 ; Zone: <root> ; 
    Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:


Can't bind to 'ngModal' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. (" <mat-form-field>
       <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" [ERROR ->][(ngModal)]="picker"  >            
       <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker"): ng:///app/dashboard/dashboard.component.html@3:81
```

When I remove the ngModal it works fine.

I have already imported FormsModule in app.module.

Can someone please help me with a solution

Answer (score 2):

The correct directive is NgMod**e**l and not NgMod**a**l.

In general, the error you have is due to either the module that define the directive is not imported in your component's module or you misspelled the directive selector.

Here is the link to the official doc: https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#your-directive-isnt-working

Comment: I have corrected the ngModal to ngModel. This is the error I get.                         "Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot assign to a reference or variable! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!"

Comment: In your template, you should change #picker reference varible name because it's already defined in the component class.

Comment: Yes, I have changed the name of picker in ngModel to a different name and it works now. Thanks

Comment: I have found a solution that ngmodel name should not be same as date picker name. I changed the ngmodel name to fromDatePicker. That solved my problem.